# handle empty collections as null in Dozer mapping

Tags: java, mapping, dozer

i am using dozer to convert business Pojos to userPojo. i can use map-null=false to avoid converting null collections to destination object but i want to handle empty collection in a similar way. not able to find anything suitable to my requirement.

Answer (score 0):

One of the possible way is to use a `CustomConverter` and fine tune the conversion process as per your need.

[Please have a look here](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/documentation/customconverter.html)

Comment: i can use custom converter but how will i map internal objects ? using customer converter for simple objects is fine, like Enum to Enum, String to String,etc but Collection<A> to Collection<B>, i need a handle on the mapper too.

Comment: Converters can be used between 2 classes(where entire conversion is your responsibility) or to some individual fields of the classes, whatever be the type. The method to implement is `public Object convert(Object destination, Object source, 
      Class destClass, Class sourceClass)', where you can easily check if the object is instance of Collection and if is empty, before converting. Please go through the link I provided. There are plenty of examples to help.

Comment: i want something like an interceptor. if collection is empty dont convert, else continue using the default conversion by dozer.